# Classifying an array

Tags: python, numpy

For instance I have this list:

```
A = [(1, 2.5), (2, 5.0), (3, 7.5), (4, 10.0)]
```

and I have another list with the following entry:

```
B = [2.5, 7.5, 12.5]
```

What I want is a program in Python where if the 2nd element of each tuple in `A`, namely `2.5`, `5.0`, `7.5`, and `10.0`, can be found in `B`, it will create another variable which looks like this:

```
C = [(1, 2.5), (3, 7.5)]
```

where it removes the other tuples in `A` whose 2nd elements are not in `B`. I tried to code it this way:

```
A = [(1, 2.5), (2, 5.0), (3, 7.5), (4, 10.0)]
D = np.asarray(list(A))
E = []
if D[:, 1] in B:
    E = np.append(E,D)
else:
    pass
```

but I got an error of:

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Comment: Is `7,5` in `B` a typo for `7.5`?

Comment: B is also never defined `if D[:,1] in B:`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [np.n1d](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html) to determine which values in `A[:, 1]` are also in `B`:

```
In [104]: A = np.array([(1,2.5), (2,5.0), (3,7.5), (4,10.0)])

In [105]: B = [2.5, 7.5, 12.5]

In [106]: mask = np.in1d(A[:, 1], B)

In [107]: mask
Out[107]: array([ True, False,  True, False], dtype=bool)

In [108]: A[mask]
Out[108]: 
array([[ 1. ,  2.5],
       [ 3. ,  7.5]])
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not simply the following:

```
>>> A = [(1,2.5), (2,5.0), (3,7.5), (4,10.0)]
>>> B = [2.5, 7,5, 12.5]
>>> C = [a for a in A if a[1] in B]
>>> C
[(1, 2.5), (3, 7.5)]
```

Comment: Because iterating in native Python - whether with a comprehension or a loop - usually defeats the purpose of Numpy.